# Angular Konva : Cannot read property 'Stage' of undefined

Tags: angular, konvajs

I am using angular environment with following versions.

> Angular CLI: 7.3.9
>
> Node: 10.10.0
>
> OS: linux x64
>
> Angular: 7.2.14

And the project includes

> konva@4.0.10

Angular starts without any compilation errors.
But when the app starts in the browser getting an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Stage' of undefined

What may cause for the issue ?